# Updating database throws errors in To Do List app

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and working on a simple To Do list app.

It contains a function that updates the UI whenever an item from the To Do list is deleted or added. A description of the To do´s should be added, as well the option to mark them as a favorite To do and an expiration date. Therefore, I added three more fields to the Database helper class.

This is my TaskDBhelper.java class:

```
package com.example.TodoList.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT)", TaskContract.TABLE,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.TASK,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.TEXT,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.DATE,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.FAVOURITE
                                    );
        Log.d("TaskDBHelper", "Query to form table: " + sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.TABLE);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

This is my TaskContract.java:

```
package com.example.TodoList.db;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class TaskContract {
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.example.TodoList.db.tasks";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE = "tasks";


    public static class Columns {
        public static final String TASK = "task";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String TEXT = "text";
        public static final String FAVOURITE = "favourite";
        public static final String DATE = "date";
    }
}
```

This is the updateUI() function in the MainActivity.java which throws the errors, when the Activity is rendered:

```
private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.TEXT,
                        String.valueOf(TaskContract.Columns.FAVOURITE), TaskContract.Columns.DATE},
                null, null, null, null, null
            );


        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK},    //TaskContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION },
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
```

I get the following error message when running the app:

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: text (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, task, text, favourite, date FROM tasks"
```

Any hints would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Might I suggest using a LoaderManager. Life will be much easier this way: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatching parenthesis...

```
Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE, // <-- open parenthesis
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.TEXT },
                null, null, null, null, null); // <-- close parenthesis with semi-colon. Cursor has been defined. 
                new Boolean []{TaskContract.Columns.FAVOURITE}, // <-- unexpected token error here
                null, null, null); // <-- Additional close parenthesis
                new Integer []{TaskContract.Columns.DATE },
                null, null, null); // <-- I suspect this is where you meant to end the cursor?
```

Comment: I updated my question. Any hints on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @DWA2112 - You have already accepted this answer for your initial problem. I suggest you make a new post and I will gladly answer it.

Comment: I would like to, but Stack Overflow doesn´t allows me to do this at the moment; therefore, I made several changes to my question, as I still have this problem and would very much appreciate the help of the community and any further hints, Thanks!

Comment: @DWA2112 - The immediate problem that I see is that your `String.format` is missing 3 `%s`, so the error "no such column text" means you created the table wrong. Learn to read your logcat and see where you log `sqlQuery`. Please [see here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_table.htm) for examples on table creation.